what is a Solana in Python
I have a question about how to interact with DEX on Solana via Python.
How can I interpret the data from this transaction https://solscan.io/tx/2pGyyR67zLzV5DbXak3ZMPVQKmRzPRUG37onm7CVe1urSMznHpdeRJzfmyzdD4gTZ65xJG1yWfR9uRedb9se3Z3z and repeat it in my code.
Before that, I worked only with EVM-networks, tell me where to dig, where to see examples of making such transactions?
I learned how to work with sending SOL and SPL tokens via solana.py and solders
